# NgMap draggable position

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps

I want to get the draggable position of the map. I set on-dragend on ng-map, but the event doesn't return the position because the map itself doesn't have position. I plan to create hidden custom marker at the center of the map. When the map is dragged, the marker will be move/drag too. The current position of that hidden custom marker will be update accordingly when the on-dragend is called.

How can I achieve this?

**View**

```
<ng-map center="{{ latitude }}, {{ longitude }}" 
          zoom="14" 
          on-dragend="dragEnd()">
    <marker icon="{{customIcon}}" position="{{ latitude }}, {{ longitude }}">
    </marker>
</ng-map>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.dragEnd = function (e) {
    console.log("EVENT: " + event); // EVENT undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Map) the `dragend` event doesn't accept any arguments:

> ```
> dragend
> ```
>
> Arguments: None This event is fired when the user stops dragging the
>   map.

Instead you could consider to update marker based on current map properties (e.g. by getting center of map using `getCenter()` function) once the map is dragged:

```
$scope.dragEnd = function () {
   $scope.pos = [$scope.map.getCenter().lat(),$scope.map.getCenter().lng()];
};
```

Example

```js
angular.module('plunker', ['ngMap'])

    .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'NgMap',
        function ($scope,NgMap) {

            NgMap.getMap().then(function (map) {
                $scope.map = map;
            });

            $scope.center = [45.026950, 15.205764];
            $scope.pos = [45.026950, 15.205764];

            $scope.dragEnd = function () {
                $scope.pos = [$scope.map.getCenter().lat(),$scope.map.getCenter().lng()];
            };

        }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>


<div ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ng-map center="{{center}}" zoom="5" on-click="getpos($event)" on-dragend="dragEnd()" style='width: 100%; margin: 15px;'>
    <marker position="{{pos}}"  animation="Animation.BOUNCE" animation="DROP"></marker>
  </ng-map>
</div>
```